# Glossary displays regular and bold math-mode text the same way

Tags: math-mode, bold, glossaries-extra

Consider the following LaTex code, where I define glossary items for two functions in math mode: one is supposed to be rendered as plain text, and the other is supposed to be rendered as bold text, however both appear the same in the glossary. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{regular}{name={\ensuremath{\text{regular}}},description={regular text in math mode}}
\newglossaryentry{bold}{name={\ensuremath{\textbf{bold}}},description={bold text in math mode}}

\begin{document}

$\text{regular}$\glsadd{regular}
$\textbf{bold}$\glsadd{bold}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The code above, saved in a file named `test.tex`, is meant to be executed with the following commands:

```
> lualatex test
> makeglossaries test
> lualatex test
```

The typeset output is:

[image: The glossary renders regular and bold math-mode text the same way]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever formatting you had set when you switch to math mode bleeds through into `\text`.  Sometimes, this is what you want (such as math expressions inside a heading).  If you meant to reset the text formatting to the default, though, use `\textnormal{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{regular}{name={\ensuremath{\textnormal{regular}}},description={regular text in math mode}}
\newglossaryentry{bold}{name={\ensuremath{\textbf{bold}}},description={bold text in math mode}}

\begin{document}
$\text{regular}$\glsadd{regular}
$\textbf{bold}$\glsadd{bold}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

If you use `\text{\mdseries ...}` or `\textmd{...}`, your text will reset the font weight but inherit the shape of the surrounding text.  The most common pitfall is that it would be italicized inside a theorem statement.  Use those if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Why does `\text{}` work in the body of the document, but not in the glossary?

Comment: @EvanAad Probably by coincidence. If you used it inside an emphasized section, it wouldn’t (if I understand you correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\mdseries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{regular}{name={\ensuremath{\text{\mdseries regular}}},description={regular text in math mode}}
\newglossaryentry{bold}{name={\ensuremath{\textbf{bold}}},description={bold text in math mode}}

\begin{document}

$\text{regular}$\glsadd{regular}
$\textbf{bold}$\glsadd{bold}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]